# matlab16 vision.VideoFileReader showing error in ubuntu

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, ubuntu-16.04

i have been using matlab 2015b on windows just recently i switched to 2016b on Ubuntu

```
 Error using VideoFileReader/setup
    Could not open the specified file.

Error in matlab.system.mixin.FiniteSource/isDone

Error in draw_boxes (line 11)
while ~isDone(videoFReader)
```

i got the above error when i tried to run the following code on on 2016b Ubuntu

```
    % Load the video using a video reader object.
videoFReader = vision.VideoFileReader('pp1_2.avi');
%%
% Create a video player object to play the video file.
videoPlayer = vision.VideoPlayer;
%%
% Use a while loop to read and play the video frames.
while ~isDone(videoFReader)
  videoFrame = videoFReader();
  videoPlayer(videoFrame);
end
%%
% Release the objects.
release(videoPlayer);
release(videoFReader);
```

but it had given an error. it it had not given any error for the built in video sequence ecolli.avi. the path of the video is correct as i have checked it.pp1_2.avi is the video that i am working on

i have tried some methods as stated in the website http://mukeshchomu.blogspot.in/2015/04/ubuntu-matlab-error-using.html like installing gstreamer but it have'nt worked for me yet

any help would be appreciated. thanks in advance

Comment: Is pp1_2.avi file in your current directory from where you run the script or in MATLAB path?

Comment: yes it is @Navan.... i think its some problem relating to ubuntu version matlabs